# For each element in class, console.log its value

Tags: javascript, jquery

For each element with the class `the_name`, I want to alert the value inside that element. So for the code below, it should alert three times. Once each for: "apples", "pears", and "plums".

Not sure what I am missing here.

```js
var arr = $('.the_name');
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
  alert(arr[i].val());  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="datatable">
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th></th>
   <th>Fruits</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td class="the_name">Apples</td>
   <td class="the_count">3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td class="the_name">Pears</td>
   <td class="the_count">2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td class="the_name">Plums</td>
   <td class="the_count">5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Bananas</td>
   <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Oranges</td>
   <td>2</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: `$(arr[0]).text()` or `$('.the_name').each(function(){alert($(this).text())})`

Comment: `arr[i]` is a dom element reference so dont have access to jQuery methods.. also the elements are `td` elements so need to get its text not value

Comment: Or `arr[i].innerText`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By accessing the jQuery object by index you're retrieving the underlying DOMElement, not the jQuery object, and they do not have a `val()` method. Also note that you seems to be looking to retrieve the text of the element, not the value. As such, you should use `each()` to loop over the selected elements, using `this` to refer to the element of the current iteration. Try this:

```
$('.the_name').each(function() {
    alert($(this).text());  
});
```

Also note that for debugging purposes, `console.log()` should be used instead of `alert()`.

```js
$('.the_name').each(function() {
  alert($(this).text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="datatable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>Fruits</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="the_name">Apples</td>
      <td class="the_count">3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="the_name">Pears</td>
      <td class="the_count">2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="the_name">Plums</td>
      <td class="the_count">5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Bananas</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Oranges</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I could not get this solution to work.  When I look at the log, all I see is a number three, I guess which represents that console.log was called three times: https://jsfiddle.net/L4pn4rg4/

Comment: Updated the answer with an example for you. Your original example was using `val()`, yet you need to use `text()`.

Answer (score 1):

1. you need to use `.text()` instead of `.val()`.
   `.val()` works on input elements (or any element with a value attribute?) and `.text()` will not work on input elements.  `.val()` gets the value of the input element -- regardless of type. `.text()` gets the innerText (not HTML) of all the matched elements:

[`.text()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/text)

> The result is a string that contains
>   the combined text contents of all
>   matched elements. This method works on
>   both HTML and XML documents. Cannot be
>   used on input elements. For input
>   field text use the val attribute.

[`.val()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/val)

> Get the content of the value attribute
>   of the first matched element

2. you need to use use `$` to use `jquery` method `.text()`.

```js
var arr = $('.the_name');
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){

  alert($(arr[i]).text());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="datatable">
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th></th>
   <th>Fruits</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td class="the_name">Apples</td>
   <td class="the_count">3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td class="the_name">Pears</td>
   <td class="the_count">2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td class="the_name">Plums</td>
   <td class="the_count">5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Bananas</td>
   <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Oranges</td>
   <td>2</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

The indexed values of a jQuery object are HTML elements, not jQuery objects.

You have to wrap them in a jQuery object before you can call jQuery methods on them:

```
var arr = $('.the_name');
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
  var html_element = arr[i];
  var $html_element = $(html_element);
  alert($html_element.val());  
}
```